# Adding combinations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show non-numerically that:

$${2\choose2} + {3\choose2} + {4\choose2} + {5\choose2} = {6\choose3}$$

The answer is as follows, but I have no idea how it was done:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
&\phantom{=}& {2\choose2} + {3\choose2} + {4\choose2} + {5\choose2} \\
&=& {3\choose3} + {3\choose2} + {4\choose2} + {5\choose2} \\
&=& {4\choose3} + {4\choose2} + {5\choose2} \\
&=& {5\choose3} + {5\choose2} \\
&=& {6\choose3}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Could anyone please explain this? Thank you!

Comment: Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle

Comment: This is a case of the [hockey-stick identity](http://luckytoilet.wordpress.com/2010/10/22/the-hockey-stick-theorem-an-animated-proof/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to think about it is that in order to pick 3 out 6 one thing you can do is to pick the 6th one and then pick 2 out of the first 5... or you can skip the sixth one, pick the fifth one and then 2 out of the first 4, or you can skip 5 and 6 but pick the fourth one and 2 out of the first 3, or skip numbers 4, 5 and, but then you must pick the third plus 2 out of the first 2 (since you have to have 3 of the original 6). That means C(6,3) = C(5,2) + C(4,2) + C(3,2) + C(2.2).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to choose $k$ items from $n$ items, you can do either way:

1. choose $k$ items from the first $n-1$ items.
2. choose the last item, and then choose $k-1$ items from the first $n-1$ items.

That means

${n\choose k} = {n-1\choose k} + {n-1\choose k-1}$